# Cloning the map layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, copy, group-layer, qgsvectorlayer

I want to clone my generated memory layer and apply different filters and symbology. The clone is visible in the layer tree, but doesn't show up in the canvas. What am I doing wrong?

```py
uri = f'point?crs=EPSG:25832&field=id:integer&index=yes'
l_out = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'new layer', 'memory')

x, y = 369000, 5616000
with edit(l_out):
    for i in range(10):
        f = QgsFeature(l_out.fields())
        g = QgsGeometry(QgsPoint(x, y))
        f.setGeometry(g)
        f.setAttributes([i])
        l_out.addFeature(f)
        x += 50
        y += 50

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.addMapLayer(l_out)

tree = project.layerTreeRoot()
group0 = tree.insertGroup(0, 'level 0')
group1 = group0.addGroup('level 1')

lcopy = project.addMapLayer(l_out.clone(), False)
nodecopy = group1.insertLayer(-1, lcopy)
```

Comment: If you use fix geometry it works. The first layer that is visible has memory://point?crs=EPSG:25832. The second before fixing has memory://memory?geometry=Point&crs=EPSG:25832, after fixing memory://Point?crs=EPSG:25832. you dont get any errors that had been fixed, not in qgis fixing and not in v.clean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several suggestions regarding your code:

- adding the same layer `l_out` one more time to the project, even with the `addToLegend = False` does not make much sense to me. In the documentation for the [`addMapLayer()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a9e9cf6a97f67d17b26faf95a6124cdf4) method, it says what `Returns` it possesses:

  > `nullptr` if unable to add layer, otherwise pointer to newly added layer

  However, the type of the `lcopy`-variable is the `QgsVectorLayer`. On the another side, the `insertLayer()` method works with `QgsMapLayer` and `QgsVectorLayer`.
- no need to create the `nodecopy`-object, simply proceed with:

  ```py
  group1.insertLayer(-1, lcopy)
  ```
- application of these methods i.e. [`isValid()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#ab4d304ac4e8fbd610a00adfa4871845b) and [`hasFeatures()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aec543b3c717f3d486d4c0791ce5eab31) can be useful to check if your `QgsVectorLayer` is solid:

  ```py
  if l_out.isValid() and l_out.hasFeatures():
     ...
  ```

I can also suggest several workarounds:

1. using the [`findLayer()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeGroup.html#afaac440af412eece5161da41dad12ba1) method of the `QgsLayerTreeGroup` class:

   ```py
   project = QgsProject.instance()
   project.addMapLayer(l_out)

   tree = project.layerTreeRoot()

   group0 = tree.insertGroup(0, 'level 0')
   group1 = group0.addGroup('level 1')

   layer = tree.findLayer(l_out.id()) # QgsLayerTreeLayer
   lcopy = layer.clone() # QgsLayerTreeLayer
   group1.insertChildNode(0, lcopy)
   ```
2. proceeding without cloning:

   ```py
   project = QgsProject.instance()
   project.addMapLayer(l_out)

   tree = project.layerTreeRoot()
   group0 = tree.insertGroup(0, 'level 0')
   group1 = group0.addGroup('level 1')

   group1.insertLayer(-1, l_out)
   ```
3. applying the [`materialize()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureSource.html#ab95bcca99b1d5c082ca409da04e280b9) method:

   ```py
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    project.addMapLayer(l_out)

    tree = project.layerTreeRoot()
    group0 = tree.insertGroup(0, 'level 0')
    group1 = group0.addGroup('level 1')

    lcopy = l_out.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(l_out.allFeatureIds())) # QgsVectorLayer
    group1.insertLayer(-1, lcopy)
   ```

Comment: Before editing this answer you suggested using `layer.materialize()`. That worked for me and so I could finish a projekt in time :). Your workaround with `findLayer` clones the complete layer tree node including the layer itself, that's appealing. As @Xeppit notes, my clone had the source prefix "memory?geometry=Point&" instead of "point?". I wonder if that syntax is valid or if this is a bug in `clone()`.

Comment: My error, `findlayer().clone()` clones the node, but not the layer: I can't set individual filters on the clones. So I have to stay with `layer.materialize()`.